# Keep getting OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError on one environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ssl

I keep getting the following error using a Rails console to interface with a library that interfaces with a web service over HTTPS. The web service is up and works properly and all the other machines in my dev group can run the library appropriately except this one so I am about 99% sure it is a environment issue. I keep trying to figure out how to solve it and am stumped currently. The error I am getting is:

`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

I am using ruby-2.0.0-p653 and OpenSSL 0.9.8zg on Mac OSX El Capitan.

Comment: Try using this. I remember I had a similar issue to you. https://github.com/stevegraham/certified

Comment: I'll try it in the morning, thanks!! Been such a PITA man!

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: try using openssl version 1.0+

Comment: we tried using the latest version of openssl installed from homebrew (something like 1.0.2d or something similar) and linking directly from the keg that gets installed to overwrite the default osx install. it didn't help. the strangest part is that rvm and everything else (ie curl, etc) that references openssl says it is verifying things properly its just when rails c was used (and the ruby wrapper for openssl that OpenSSL gem was using) that problems occurred

Comment: Can you post the full trace? What library is causing a problem? Might want to post this as an issue in the repo on github.

Comment: Good call. It was in the net http library from what I remember. Since we got a work around temporarily i hadn't logged the problem. I should double check on that again.